# Extract text from all nodes from XML placed in Clob field Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I am new to XML and I want to extract text from XML loaded in a table having CLOB column type.

Since there are leaf nodes, I am not able to get a clue.The XML is quite big, this is just a snippet,if I can work this out I'll try to implement for the whole XML.

I have the below query but I am not getting any value for service id

```
   SELECT *
    FROM XML_T y
    ,XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES('all the name spaces'),
                    '//e:DocumentServiceID'
                    --/e:DocumentHeader/e:DocumentServiceID'
                        PASSING XMLTYPE.createxml(y.xmlty) 
                        COLUMNS service_id varchar2(200) path '@DocumentServiceID'
                              /*  factext varchar2(100) path '@FacText',
                                fac varchar2(100) path '@Fac',
                                st_name varchar2(100) path './StreetName',
                                zipcode varchar2(10) path './PostalCode',
                            */
);
```

I have put the the below into a table

```
<?XML VERSION="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<E:EnDatDoc xmlns:ext="http://qbc.net/de/City/A-Ex/1.0" xmlns:df="http://xyz.ht.net/yy/Asset/1.0" xmlns:nc="http://pol.org/ni-core/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:E="http://www.yup.net/enterprise">
    <E:DocumentHeader>
     <E:DocumentServiceID>A_PUSH</E:DocumentServiceID>
     </E:DocumentHeader>
        <E:DocumentBody>
            <df:PropertyRecord>
                    <ext:Facility>
                                <nc:FacText>A9</nc:FacText>
                                <ext:Fac>One St</ext:Fac>
                                <nc:Facility>
                                    <nc:LocationAddress>
                                        <nc:Addr>
                                            <nc:Street>
                                                <nc:StreetName>18 STR</nc:StreetName>
                                            </nc:Street>
                                        <nc:PostalCode>07854</nc:PostalCode>
                                        </nc:Addr>
                                    </nc:LocationAddress>
                                </nc:Facility>
                            <ext:Item>
                                <nc:MeasureText>40.99</nc:MeasureText>
                                <nc:length>SF</nc:length>
                            </ext:Item>
                            <ext:Gross>
                                <nc:MeasureText>90.00</nc:MeasureText>
                                <nc:Length>SF</nc:Length>
                            </ext:Gross>
                            <nc:ItemWidth>
                                <nc:MeasureText>24.83</nc:MeasureText>
                                <nc:length>FT</nc:length>
                            </nc:ItemWidth>
                            <ext:Irregular>FALSE</ext:Irregular>
                            <ext:Floors>1</ext:Floors>
                        <ext:Cons>
                            <nc:StartDate>
                                <nc:YEAR>1977</nc:YEAR>
                            </nc:StartDate>
                        </ext:Cons>
                        <ext:Conflg>TRUE</ext:Conflg>
                        <ext:Tax>
                            <ext:Classtext>1</ext:Classtext>
                            <ext:Cdesc>1 - 3 Units</ext:Cdesc>
                        </ext:Tax>
                    </ext:Facility>
            </df:PropertyRecord>
        </E:DocumentBody>
     </E:EnDatDoc>
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service, you need to research Oracle's XML functions and try to write a query, not ask someone to do that work for you. You also haven't shown what you want to extract or what output you're expecting.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have a sample query which I read some document and figured out ,but I'm still not getting the output for service id.I have edited the question and put the query there

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to extract all the text part of the xml,hence for that do I have to create mapping for each text value and assign to a column

Comment: Yes, essentially, since each value has to be associated with a column name if you're looking at it relationally. It's more complicated if there are any sequences within each PropertyRecord, or Facility, or whichever level you're extracting from; there don't seem to be in that snippet though. You seem to be using the `@` syntax to look at attributes, rather than element values..

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, I need to associate each value to a column. There is no sequences.I need to figure out how to get element values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the full path to each (leaf) node you want to extract, relative to the node identified by the XPath. You also need to refer to the element, not an attribute (with the '@ syntax you were using).

```
select x.*
from xml_t y
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://qbc.net/de/City/A-Ex/1.0' as "ext",
    'http://xyz.ht.net/yy/Asset/1.0' as "df",
    'http://pol.org/ni-core/2.0' as "nc",
    'http://www.yup.net/enterprise' as "E"),
  '/E:EnDatDoc'
  passing xmltype.createxml(y.xmlty) 
  columns service_id varchar2(10) path 'E:DocumentHeader/E:DocumentServiceID',
    factext varchar2(10) path 'E:DocumentBody/df:PropertyRecord/ext:Facility/nc:FacText',
    fac varchar2(10) path 'E:DocumentBody/df:PropertyRecord/ext:Facility/ext:Fac',
    st_name varchar2(10) path 'E:DocumentBody/df:PropertyRecord/ext:Facility/nc:Facility/nc:LocationAddress/nc:Addr/nc:Street/nc:StreetName',
    zipcode varchar2(10) path 'E:DocumentBody/df:PropertyRecord/ext:Facility/nc:Facility/nc:LocationAddress/nc:Addr/nc:PostalCode'
) x;

SERVICE_ID FACTEXT    FAC        ST_NAME    ZIPCODE  
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A_PUSH     A9         One St     18 STR     07854
```

And then extend that for all the other nodes/columns you want to extract.

You *could* cheat and use wildcard namespaces and paths:

```
select x.*
from xml_t y
cross join xmltable(
  '/'
  passing xmltype.createxml(y.xmlty) 
  columns service_id varchar2(10) path '//*:DocumentServiceID',
    factext varchar2(10) path '//*:FacText',
    fac varchar2(10) path '//*:Fac',
    st_name varchar2(10) path '//*:StreetName',
    zipcode varchar2(10) path '//*:PostalCode'
) x;
```

but you may have namespace clashes (as you do with `ext:Facility` and `nc:Facility`) which will cause problems or break at some point, and unless this is an ad hoc one-off query it would be much better to be explicit and self-documenting. You and anyone reading the query can see where you're expecting each bit of information to come from.

You could also make the XPath flatten out the structure by constructing new elements which have all the information you want as attributes, but it's probably more difficult and less clear.

Comment: the query runs fine but no gives no rows :-( I'll check again if anything is missing or uppercase.I'll update you soon. Thank you so very much. Maybe I'm missing some xml related files or package on 11.2 database.

Comment: @RajA - I ran that on 11.2.0.4 using your sample XML; with the `<?XML VERSION` part changes to lowercase as uppercase was invalid. If you had anything missing it would error. So, maybe your real structure is different, or you changed the case of something.

Comment: Yup I think it's something wrong at my end, I will clean and do the whole thing again.You are truly genius,now I got some confidence and eagerness to dive more into this XML stuff.I'll finish the remaining 100+ mapping and run. You can be a very good mentor! Will let you know how it comes out

Comment: Hi Alex,
I got all the paths for approx 180+ elements,but there was an iteration 
in one of the XML & I saw your response to question # 30913923 & figured it out.
But I didn't get output for an XML which does not contain that iteration tags,whereas if I comment the iteration part for that particular XML,I get the output. What is it causing to not pull up the row if that 2nd cross join is made?

Comment: @RajA - because you're joining, and if there is no match for the join there is no result. You can't really outer join in that scenario I think ([as here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35723116/266304)). You may have to handle that in your XPath instead. I think you should ask a new question showing a (simplified) example of the issue you're having now.

Comment: Actually I had 2 attributes which were iterating so made 1 main query and 2 separate queries for elements which are iterating.All 3 query will have a common primary key. Now I can do left outer join the with main query. But I would want to try all in one single query too, so I'll try that to handle that in XPath as you suggested.Thanks again